# Trouble removing only the wanted object from ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

This is a part of a larger assignment, and I am completely new to both Java and programming in general. I am a System and Network Admin, not a developer. So things such as "studentId would be better as an int" is not helpful because String was a requirement of the assignment.

I need to remove an object from my Student objects based on the studentId. I found the code to remove an object from an ArrayList of objects here on StackOverflow, and it mostly works. The issue I am having is that if the object does not exist, I want to be able to create something that says the object does not exist. Currently, after removing the correct object (in my example a studentId of "3") it will then continue to remove the last object in the array until there is no longer an object with the index of 3. Obviously, I don't have a clue why.

```
public static void remove(String sdId){

    Iterator<Student> it = studentList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
      Student id = it.next();
      if(id.getStudentId().equals(sdId)) {
        it.remove();
      }
    }

}
```

is being called with this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    studentList = new ArrayList();
    populateStudents(); // convert array of strings to ArrayList of student objects


    ((Student)studentList.get(0)).print();
    ((Student)studentList.get(1)).print();
    ((Student)studentList.get(2)).print();
    ((Student)studentList.get(3)).print();
    ((Student)studentList.get(4)).print();

    System.out.println();
    remove("3");
    ((Student)studentList.get(0)).print();
    ((Student)studentList.get(1)).print();
    ((Student)studentList.get(2)).print();
    ((Student)studentList.get(3)).print();

    System.out.println();
    remove("3");
    ((Student)studentList.get(0)).print();
    ((Student)studentList.get(1)).print();
    ((Student)studentList.get(2)).print();
}
```

and it is outputting this:

```
1    First Name: John    Last Name: Smith    E-mail: John1989@gmail.com  Age: 20     Grades: {88, 79, 59}
2    First Name: Suzan   Last Name: Erickson     E-mail: Erickson_1990@gmailcom  Age: 19     Grades: {91, 72, 85}
3    First Name: Jack    Last Name: Napoli   E-mail: The_lawyer99yahoo.com   Age: 19     Grades: {85, 84, 87}
4    First Name: Erin    Last Name: Black    E-mail: Erin.black@comcast.net  Age: 22     Grades: {91, 98, 82}
5    First Name: John    Last Name: Reid     E-mail: JohnReid@WGU.edu    Age: 44     Grades: {98, 99, 98}

1    First Name: John    Last Name: Smith    E-mail: John1989@gmail.com  Age: 20     Grades: {88, 79, 59}
2    First Name: Suzan   Last Name: Erickson     E-mail: Erickson_1990@gmailcom  Age: 19     Grades: {91, 72, 85}
4    First Name: Erin    Last Name: Black    E-mail: Erin.black@comcast.net  Age: 22     Grades: {91, 98, 82}
5    First Name: John    Last Name: Reid     E-mail: JohnReid@WGU.edu    Age: 44     Grades: {98, 99, 98}

1    First Name: John    Last Name: Smith    E-mail: John1989@gmail.com  Age: 20     Grades: {88, 79, 59}
2    First Name: Suzan   Last Name: Erickson     E-mail: Erickson_1990@gmailcom  Age: 19     Grades: {91, 72, 85}
4    First Name: Erin    Last Name: Black    E-mail: Erin.black@comcast.net  Age: 22     Grades: {91, 98, 82}
```

In the last group of prints, if I had called it a fourth time I get an outOfBounds. I have not created a loop for the output primarily as it is just for testing and is not what will actually get used -- I have not yet created that function.

Comment: First:  why are you using a raw type with your `ArrayList`?  Declare it with `ArrayList<Student> studentList` and you won't ever have to do any casts again.  Second:  instead of printing each element individually, why not print the list instead?  Move whatever information is in that `print` method to a `public String toString()` method instead and just call `System.out.println(studentList);`.

Comment: You need to show us the Student class. Post a **complete** program reproducing the problem. Also post the actual code that causes the exception, and the stack trace of that exception.

Comment: Agreed, there is something missing here. Your remove function looks correct.

Comment: Show us your populateStudents() method. Is it possible all your students have id "3"

Comment: @Makoto - As I stated I am completely new, the answer being I don't know any better.

Comment: Can you post you populateStudents() method and your Students class.

Comment: @JB NIzet -- can not do that. This is an assignment. I can not let another student Google search how to do this in its (almost) entirety.

Comment: @bhspencer -- for that same reason as above I can not do that, it would show a solution to a big part to the over all assignment.  I can tell you that there are a total of five students and the studentId is 1 through 5 inclusive, and they are strings. There is no duplication.

Comment: I guess I could post them on http://collabedit.com/ and take them down after I find a solution. Let me check to see if it is possible to delete them when I am done.

Comment: It looks like collabedit allows me to purge history when done. so . . .

Roster.java -- http://collabedit.com/3yqwd
Student.java -- http://collabedit.com/vsjde

Comment: @JohnC.Reid Try to use my remove method below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a student object based on the ID. I will assume you want to remove `one and only one` student every time you call the remove method.

Hence, you should not be using a while-loop to iterate through the list. A for-loop will be suitable to get the student object holding the ID you want to remove.

```
public static void remove(String sdId){
    Student stud = null;
    for(Student s : studentList){
        if(s.getStudentId().equals(sdId))
            stud = s;
    }
    if(stud != null)
        studentList.remove(stud);
    else
        System.out.println("ID does not exist."); //optional
}
```

This will ensure you only remove 1 student and if the ID does not exist, the remove method does nothing. Of course, you can also use an iterator to iterate through the list.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. Like I said, like most of what I have put together I found my code by searching. I still don't have a great understanding, and the light bulb has not quite yet gone off.

I will play with this and see what it yields me.

Comment: @JohnC.Reid If it doesn't work, it should be other parts of your codes giving you problem. According to what you need, the above is suffice. Let me know the outcome anyway, I can try to help you do some fixing before I sleep.

Comment: It appears to be working. Can I simply add an else statement to this for my error if the student does not exist?

Comment: Do not print from inside a remove method - bad practice. If you need something of that form return a boolean and do a check in the calling code and output there. @JohnC.Reid

Comment: No code in comments on a coding website -- how odd!

Thank you for your quick assistance. This helped greatly.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I raise 2 hands agreeing on your statement. I even contemplated changing his method to non-static with boolean return type. But from OP's current state, I just try to give him what he needs - something which works within his understanding.